# Update records inside while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a list of hearings in a table named Hearings and I want to update the Hearings.UserID value from the list in Hearings_Users.UserID.  There will always more Hearings than Hearings Users so I'll need to loop through the list of users and start over again in a round-robin fashion so each user has roughly the same number of hearings.

I just want to update 1 row at a time. The result will just be an updated list in the Hearings table where each record was updated with a UserID from the Hearings_Users table. For example, if there are 20 hearings and 4 users, each UserID in the Hearings will be updated with 5 rows each.   If there were 19 hearings, then there would be 5,5,5,4 each.

**Hearings**

[image]

**Hearings_Users**

[image]

**Desired Results After Update**

[image]

```
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 Hearings_CaseID
                 FROM Hearings
                 WHERE UserID IS NULL)
          UPDATE Hearings
          SET UserID = (SELECT UserID
                        FROM Hearings_Users
                        WHERE Active = 1)
```

This produces an endless loop and just the UPDATE clause produces
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Easier / more appropriate “solution” would be to not use a loop. In any case, the “non-termination issue” is because of the reason described in a warning. Use a TOP 1 in the sub-select as well to fix the immediate “error”.. although, really avoid the  loop entirely (which should also make the logic more clear).

Comment: SQL uses set based logic most of the time.  Can you edit your question and instead show us sample input along with the output you want?

Comment: How many rows do you want to be updated each time and what should the **single** value (for each row) be?

Comment: If I use a " Use a TOP 1 in the sub-select as well" then all of the hearings are just updated with the first person in the Hearings_Users table. I need it to read through the Hearings_Users table and update each hearing in a round-robin approach until are there aren't any additional Hearings with NULL UserID values.

Comment: I guess giving sample data and expected result would help us more to help you.

Comment: I added some sample data